# find missing column name and row no of datacolum in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable having around 50-60 columns

**i have a list like this**

```
  public List<string> strImportRequiredFields = new List<string> { "ENTRY/CMD #", "PART #", "REFERENCE 1", "REFERENCE 2", "REFERENCE 3", "DUTY PER" };
```

these are the mandatory columns that should be in Datatable and its value should not blank

If the value is blank it will return me row number along with column name, if possible with , separated

I have gone through many links and wrap up with this query

```
List<DataRow> dtlist = dtUploadedDat.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            var result = dtlist.Where(p => strImportRequiredFields.Any(t => p[t].ToString().Length <= 0)).ToList();

            string rstring = string.Join(",", result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

its giving me only the count value, i tried with different conditions but not getting it sort out

as the table may contains 1000s of 1000 record, so it will be really very bad if i will have to run the loop to check it

i want to make it done with linq

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: can you provide little sample input and output what you want?

Comment: @Grundy what else needed, i have given the mandatory fields list, and datatable will have around 50-60 fields out of which these fields should not be blank

Comment: but in your condition you test that at least one not blank, not all

Comment: @Grundy I am very much new to linq, i tried with the links i got

Comment: try code from my answer

Comment: I tried, how will it give me the column name and row number

Answer (score 0):

you make some little optimization

```
List<DataRow> dtlist = dtUploadedDat.AsEnumerable();

var result = dtlist.Where(p => strImportRequiredFields.All(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p[t].ToString()))); //check that all mandatory field not blank

string rstring = string.Join(",", result);
```

**UPDATE**
you can try something like this

```
var result = from r in dtlist.AsEnumerable().Select((r, i) => new { r, i })
             from colName in strImportRequiredFields

             where string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(r.r[colName ]))
             group new { col = colName , rowIndex = r.i } by colName into g
             select new { col=g.Key, rows=string.Join(",", g.Select(a=>a.rowIndex))};

string rstring = string.Join("; ", result.Select(a => a.col + ": " + a.rows));
```

Comment: but it will return me the column name and row number

Comment: @MAkela I just do not understand what is required :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = dtUploadedDat.AsEnumerable()
             .SelectMany((row,i)=>dtUploadedDat.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  .Where(col=>!strImportRequiredFields.Contains(col.ColumnName)||
                               Convert.ToString(row[col]) == string.Empty)
                  .Select(col=>string.Format("{0},{1}",i+1,col.ColumnName)))
             .ToList();

//sample result
//{"ColumnA,1", "ColumnD,5", "ColumnF,8" }
```

Each item in the result will be a pair of column name and row index (separated by a comma).

Comment: col.name showing error, i made it to column name, but not able to find row.Index

Comment: will it return me a string value

Comment: @MAkela yes, that's what I said, each entry is a string as I show in the sample result (3 entries). What kind of data type do you want? Do you have any class to store the info? Or do you like an anonymous type with 2 properties (one is column name and the other is row index)?

Comment: you are saying col=>!strImportRequiredFields.Contains(col.ColumnName) as per i am getting it's checking in strimportrequiredfields, wont it reverse, and when i run code i am gettin liek

Comment: @MAkela what do you mean? Please show the result in your updated question, show any exception you got and also clarify more on the actual data type you want.

Comment: will i have to user to arrray or to list at the end of your code

Comment: "System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<System.Data.DataRow,string>"  this is i am getting

Comment: @MAkela it depends on you

Comment: i did but i am not getting the result when i do list or to arrya it shows me around 26000 thousands count value, and i have hardly 1o rows and 60 colums :(

Comment: and you are treating each row as a column row, thats y its returning me

Comment: @MAkela not sure why it didn't work, I bet you would stuck with this forever. If you provide some **simple** sample data, I'll try to test. The code is very OK to me, in the worst case, if you have 60 columns and 10 rows, the total result will have count of **600**.

Comment: This is the sample excel file which i am getting in datatable
http://www.filedropper.com/test_21

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample you can look into this

```
    private void Vaidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ENTRY/CMD #", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("REFERENCE 1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("REFERENCE 3", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = i;
            dr[1] = "This" + i.ToString();
            dr[2] = "This" + i.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dt.Rows[5][2] = "";
        dt.Rows[8][1] = "";
        //int itemFind = 157;
        //int rowindex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.Select("Id=" + itemFind).FirstOrDefault());

        //List<string> strImportRequiredFields = new List<string> { "ENTRY/CMD #", "PART #", "REFERENCE 1", "REFERENCE 2", "REFERENCE 3", "DUTY PER" };
        List<string> strImportRequiredFields = new List<string> { "ENTRY/CMD #", "REFERENCE 1", "REFERENCE 3", };
        List<string> columnsPresent = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(a => a.ColumnName).ToList();
        List<string> columnsNotPresent = strImportRequiredFields.Except(columnsPresent).ToList();

        if (columnsNotPresent != null && columnsNotPresent.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Columns must present" + Environment.NewLine + columnsNotPresent.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));
            return;
        }


        string s = strImportRequiredFields.Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + next + " is Null or");

        var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p => strImportRequiredFields.Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p[t].ToString())));

        List<int> Invalidrows = new List<int>();

        foreach (DataRow item in result)
        {
            Invalidrows.Add(dt.Rows.IndexOf(item));
        }

        if (Invalidrows != null && Invalidrows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("some of field data missing in below rows" + Environment.NewLine + Invalidrows.Aggregate(
                        new StringBuilder(),
                        (sb, x) => sb.AppendLine(x.ToString())
                    ));

            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        dt.AsEnumerable().Select((value, key) => new { value, key }).ToList()
            .ForEach(r => strImportRequiredFields.ForEach(c => { if (r.value[c].ToString().Length <= 0) sb.AppendFormat("\"row:{0},col:{1}\"", r.key, c); }));

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```